# ModuleNotFoundError When trying to import module in tests

Tags: python, import, module

I have the following directory structure:

```
repoName/
├── myPackage/
│   ├── myModule.py
│   ├── __init__.py
└── tests/
    └── test.py
```

and there is a call like

```
from myPackage.myModule import myClass
```

And when I go to run the `test.py` file (working directory `repoName/`) I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

However when I invoke the interactive interpreter at `repoName/` and manually execute `from myPackage.myModule import myClass` the import succeeds just fine. Why does it not work in the test file?

**EDIT**

Adding this to the test script seems to make it import, but I still don't understand why it is necessary:
`sys.path.append("../myPackage")`

Comment: You need a file `repoName/setup.py`.  See [here](https://packaging.python.org/) for instructions on how to create it.  Then you need to install the package by using `pip install -e .` from within the directory containing the `setup.py`, this will set up the `sys.path` entry correctly.

Answer (score -1):

In case you don't know it a really helpful syntax to run python modules in subdirectories it to use the modular path.

```
python -m tests.test
```

This little godsend has really helped me in the past!